# y sus siete hijas a cuál más diligente

Tags: traducción, gramática, uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, expresiones

In the following sentence from "El amor en los tiempos del cólera" by Gabriel García Márquez:

> Aminta Dechamps, esposa del doctor Lácides Olivella, y sus siete hijas
> a cuál más diligente, lo habían previsto todo para que el almuerzo de
> las bodas de plata fuera el acontecimiento social del año.

What does "a cuál más diligente" mean? Specifically what is the function of "a" and what does "cuál" refer to?

Does it mean: siete hijas que son más diligente que ella (esposa del doctor Lácides Olivella)?

One English version translated it to "her seven equally diligent daughters", but I cannot make sense of it, as "más diligente" clearly indicates a comparison.

PS: The "lo" in "lo habían previsto todo" refers to what?

Comment: As the question about "lo" was not answered: "lo" refers to "todo", and it is an instance of a duplicate (or redundant) direct object pronoun. More info [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32331/24236).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe lo here is used for emphasis, and can be omitted, is it right?

Comment: Yes, in this case it can be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A cuál más" is a construction meaning "each one of them" or "all of them".
So "sus siete hijas a cuál más diligente" can be translated as "his seven daughters, all of them diligent"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Following the clue I found the explanation in RAE which I copied below. I believe the English version is accurate, "más" actually indicates equality, i.e. do not know who of them is more diligent. 

"a cuál más, o a cuál menos

1. locs. advs. U. para ponderar cierta propiedad común a varias personas o cosas > cuando no se sabe en cuál de ellas destaca más. Había publicado tres novelas, a > cuál más exitosa."

Answer (score 4):

The expression "a cuál más..." implies that all of the preceding individuals (or objects) share the same quality and even somehow (unconsciously) compete in being so.

The expression should be set off by commas:

> Aminta Dechamps, esposa del doctor Lácides Olivella, y sus siete hijas **,** a cuál más diligente, lo habían previsto todo para que el almuerzo de las bodas de plata fuera el acontecimiento social del año.

as can be seen in the examples [in this site](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/a-cual-mas-no-a-cada-cual-mas/). Actually, it works as an non-restrictive or non-defining modifier.

I think the translation "all of them equally diligent" is fine but fails to convey the idea that all of them were so diligent that it was difficult to specify which was more diligent than the others.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no puedo marcar su respuesta como la respuesta correcta (solo una respuesta útil) ya que he marcado la respuesta anterior. Agradezco ambas respuestas, a cuál más correcta.

Comment: @puravidaso nótese que sí se puede cambiar en cualquier momento la respuesta que se ha marcado como correcta. No hay ninguna limitación (ni obligación) en esto: es decisión del que ha hecho la pregunta.